# Mac OS X: I accidentally clicked on the cross in the Installed tab in the app store application. Now my Pages doesn't work anymore

Tags: macos, mac-appstore, pages

I did this with pages because I thought that it would uninstalled it (I'm brand new to mac os). It didn't uninstalled it, but it did remove it from the list of installed applications.

Now when I visit the Pages page in the app store, it shows that I must purchase it again. What did I do? How can I get Pages back? I bought it already and all I want to do is fix the installation. It doesn't work at all at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

So the cross in the list of installed applications actually just hides the app but does not uninstall it. When you open the app store go to Account -> Hidden purchases. It will be there.